# Php + Mysql, add column and fill it

Tags: php, mysql

I have Php code:

```
$link_multiq = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
mysqli_set_charset($link_multiq, "utf8");

$sql = 'SET @preparedStatement = (SELECT IF(
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
     WHERE table_name = "ring" 
     AND table_schema = "test1_serv" 
     AND column_name = "date_make_count"
     ) > 0, 
     "SELECT 1;", 
     "ALTER TABLE ring ADD date_make_count DATE;UPDATE ring SET date_make_count = '2000-12-02';"
     )); 
     PREPARE alterIfNotExists FROM @preparedStatement; 
     EXECUTE alterIfNotExists; 
     DEALLOCATE PREPARE alterIfNotExists;';

mysqli_multi_query($link_multiq, $sql);     
mysqli_close($link_multiq);
```

I'm trying to add a column (if it not exist) in table, and right away fill this added column with same date (2000-12-02), all rows.
But I'm think something wrong with this code:

```
...UPDATE ring SET date_make_count = '2000-12-02';
```

I'm don't know, how to properly write this part. I've tried:

```
a) ...UPDATE ring SET date_make_count = \'2000-12-02\';
b) ...UPDATE ring SET date_make_count = \"2000-12-02\";
c) ...UPDATE ring SET date_make_count = \`2000-12-02\`;
```

and other ways, but it's not working.
Please, help!

Comment: Why on earth do you use sql side prepared statements? Why do you use prepared statement in the first place? There is no parameter there. Just execute the statements one-by-one, process their results in php and execute the next one statement if required.